# R join a table column from a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, data-science

I would like to get the corresponding values of a vector in a table from a column in another column. (just look below)

example:

Vector:

```
v = c('A', 'B', 'C')
```

Table :

```py
# key     Value
 'C'        3
 'A'        1
 'B'        2
```

When I give the vector `v` (`A, B, C`) I want to get back the corresponding values in the good order `1, 2, 3`.

In reality, the vector is the `rownames` of a dataset, and I need to replace it with the corresponding values.

I was thinking about using the `left_join` function from `Dplyr` but I would need 2 tables for this.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution in `base R`:

```r
df$Value[match(v, df$key)]

#> [1] 1 2 3
```

---

Using `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(x = Value[match(v, key)]) %>% 
  pull(x)

#> [1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all I have voted to undelete @akrun's answer.
Second here is an alternative using `which` combined with `%in%`:

```
which(v %in% df$key)

[1] 1 2 3
```